# How to assign binary value to points inside polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have three different polygon layers with some polygons that overlap. I have points that fall both inside and outside of these polygons.  I want to assign a value of 1 if a point falls inside any polygon and a value of 0 if a point is not inside any polygon.  How to do this?

Comment: Have you considered a spatial join? https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000 but first merge https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000 the three layers as you're only concerned with *any polygon of the 3 layers* then the spatial joined points will either have an ID of an intersecting polygon or -1 for not falling inside a polygon, from here you can do a select by attributes on the spatial join with other ID = -1, populate (calculate field) with 0 then switch selection and populate with 1.

Comment: If you don't want to create an output feature class you can use select layer by location https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s50000002q000000 (new selection first then add to selection for subsequent) and use the attribute table field calculator to populate the field with 1 (intersects *any* polygon) then switch select and populate the field with 0 (misses *all* polygons).

Comment: Thank you Michael - the second option worked well. For others that might have similar issue, note that I could only select features (that intersected) from one source layer at a time and used field calculator to populate those selected fields in attribute table, then moved on to the next source layer and repopulated fields and etc.

Comment: The first layer the selection option is *create new selection*, for 2nd and subsequent selecting layers change to *add to current selection* and choose the next selection layer, this will ensure that all the features that intersect *any* polygon are selected. Performing the select by location one at a time could be futile unless you exclude the features with the field set to 1 from the layer (definition query for this) otherwise at the end when you switch selection you will be overwriting the previous calculations. If you have a working method please answer your own question for future users.

Comment: Use near tool, you can set multiple layers as input. Check the table of points after.

Answer (score 1):

The following is one workflow that will produce a binary output based on point proximity to polygons.

1. [Merge](https://pro.arcgis.com/EN/PRO-APP/TOOL-REFERENCE/DATA-MANAGEMENT/merge.htm)
2. [Dissolve](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm)
3. [Spatial Join](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm)

[image]

[image]